# Shell Script - Case-insensitive matching

Tags: windows, shell, find, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

This program:

```
#!/bin/bash

find teste1 -type f -iname "**" | while read -r firstResult
do
find teste2 -type f -iname "**" | while read -r secondResult
do
firstName=${firstResult##*[/|\\]}
secondName=${secondResult##*[/|\\]}
if [[ $firstName == $secondName ]]; then
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
else
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
fi
done
done
```

I am having a bit of a problem with it, it's working quite alright, however, when the folder is as this example: /teste1/TESTE.pub /teste2/TEstE.pub, it doesn't put the file on "equal". How can I do this? I've been trying to do the find without case sensitive, meaning it should work, but it just doesn't acknowledge.

Please help.

Maybe I should just "transform" all the files names to one of the cases and then do that search? You think that would solve my problem? In terms of logic, it would work since all files would have the same casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `tr`, bash has its own built in case conversion (`${var,,}`). Also, no need for `-iname **` with find, leaving this out will match all files by default.

```
#!/bin/bash

find teste1 -type f | while read -r firstResult
do
  find teste2 -type f | while read -r secondResult
  do
    firstName="${firstResult##*[/|\\]}"
    secondName="${secondResult##*[/|\\]}"

    if [[ "${firstName,,}" == "${secondName,,}" ]]; then
      echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
    else
      echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: It gives the following -> teste.sh: ${firstName,,}: bad substitution

Comment: I think this is due to a different bug in the script, I think your `read` is executing in a subshell. If I am right your answer will give empty `.lst` files. Hang on while I check this...

Comment: Hmm.. The ".lst" as it were, wasn't empty, it always saved a file. The problem is occurring before the whole ".lst" files, no? The bug I got was at the 'if' command or that's what it seems to me :)

Comment: Ok, I was talking rubbish. The command works for me. You will need the quotes around the substitution (added) if the filenames have contain any whitespace characters, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: This also won't work on older versions of bash (<4.0).

Comment: Damn, still not working out for me :( I think it's because my version is older than that :/ Oh well, I'll mark yours as the "Answer" for others that do have the bash version over 4.0, please add that information to your answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, I solved the problem I was having by changing all the file names to lower case.

```
#!/bin/bash

find teste1 -type f | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | while read -r firstResult
do
find teste2 -type f | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | while read -r secondResult
do
firstName=${firstResult##*[/|\\]}
secondName=${secondResult##*[/|\\]}
if [[ $firstName == $secondName ]]; then
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> equal.lst
else
echo "$firstResult" "$secondResult" >> notEqual.lst
fi
done
done
```

It is now matching and saving the files exactly as I wanted. In case other people wonder, if you want this `FIND` to be case-sensitive, just remove the `tr [A-Z] [a-z]` command.